# how to only allow letters to be used python statment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm making a Morse code program:

```
def main ():

    morse_code = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
                  "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}

    phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")
    for key in phrase:
        print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
        print(morse_code[key], end = " ")
    if phrase == int or float:
        print("try the input")

    retry()
def retry ():
    main()
retry()
main()
```

How do I print an error if someone enters a number?

Comment: format your code properly please

Comment: `print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")` should be before the beginning of for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:-

```
morse_code = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
              "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}

phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")

if any(char.isdigit() for char in phrase):
    print("try the input")
else:
    print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
    code = ' '.join(morse_code[key] for key in phrase)
    print(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isdigit`

```
for key in phrase:
    if not key.isdigit():
        print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
        print(morse_code[key], end = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input is between `a` and `z` by doing:

```
try:
    index = ord(key.lower())
    if index >= 97 and index <= 122:
        # Do your thing
except TypeError:
    # Wrong input
```

The `TypeError` shouldn't happen, it's just good practice to wrap code with errors handling.

Or, you can do:

```
if not key.isdigit():
    # Key isn't between 0 and 9. Can be uppercase or a symbol, though.
    if ord(key.lower()) >= 97 and ord(key.lower()) <= 122:
        # Do your thing. It's pretty much the same as before but with one more step.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem you will have is that the if statement is A: after the printing out of the Morsecode version of the letter, and B: it is outside of the for loop completely.

You can rectify this by putting it in the for loop before the printing like so:

```
phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")
print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
for key in phrase:
if phrase == int or float:
    print("try the input")
else:

    print(morse_code[key], end = " ")
```

However the above code still won't work, as the way you are checking if the current letter being printed out is a int or float isn't how you do it.

The easiest method is to change the codition of the if statement to `if key.isdigit():`

This will leave you with this final block of code:

```
phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")
print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
for key in phrase:
    if key.isdigit:
        print("try the input")
    else:

        print(morse_code[key], end = " ")
```

This now works, however, lets say I enter `abc123`. The output I would get is `.-
-...
-.-.
try the input
try the input`

as the code is running the forloop regardless of if there are numbers in the input or not. To prevent this, you should check the input for numbers, before you have the for loop printing out the morse code.

```
phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")

while not phrase.isalpha():
    phrase = input("invalid input: ")
print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
for key in phrase:

    print(morse_code[key], end = " ")
```

If you need any help, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

> Using isdigit() will solve your problem also use break to receive new input

```
morse_code = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
              "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}
Morse_Parse=[]
phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")
print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
for key in  range(0,len( phrase)):
    if phrase[key].isdigit():
        print("you inderted an digit , Try another input")

        break 
    else:
        Morse_Parse.append(morse_code[phrase[key]]+" ")


print("Morse for your input is "Morse_Parse)
```

> using flag will improve print task

```
morse_code = {"a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..",
              "m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."}
Morse_Parse=[]
phrase = input("please enter your word or words: ")
print("your word or sentence translated to morse code is : ")
flag=1
for key in  range(0,len( phrase)):
    if phrase[key].isdigit():
        print("you inderted an digit , Try another input")
        flag=0
        break 
    else:
        Morse_Parse.append(morse_code[phrase[key]]+" ")

if flag==1:

        print("Morse for your input is "Morse_Parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to only allow letters
>
> How do I print an error if someone enters a number?

The second case is covered easily by checking `.isdigit` on each character as others mentioned. But I will cover the first case.

Start by defining a string of valid characters. Assuming your valid character set is lowercase a-z, this would be the same as `string.ascii_lowercase`

```
import string
valid_characters = string.ascii_lowercase  # a-z

def char_valid(c):
    '''Check if a character is valid, returns True/False'''
    return c in valid_characters

def phrase_valid(phrase):
    '''Check if the phrase is valid, returns True/False'''
    return all(char_valid(char) for char in phrase)


while True:
    user_phrase = input('Enter some characters')
    if phrase_valid(user_phrase):
        # If the phrase is valid, end the loop
        break
    else:
        print('That was not a valid phrase')
        # the loop continues and will ask for input again
```

This pattern works any time you want to keep asking for input until it is valid.